# How to keep a specific bit set all the time for bit masking I2C operations?

Tags: c, variables

I've been working on I2C and I learned how to initialize, send and receive with I2C communication protocol.

Next, I wanted to run the LCD1602 I2C adapter. But the module has a different bit masking, it turns out that I have to keep a specific bit set so I can control the remaining 7-bits, because otherwise I can't control the upper 4-bits if this bit is 0.

So, I put the 8-bit variable for the bit masking operations in the global section and initialize it with uint8_T bitmasking = 0x08; but it's volatile. I used static keyword, but the bit is not constant.

So what's the solution?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

'static' just avoids reinitialization and is used for local vars in timed interrupts for example.

`volatile` is another keyword you should not be using without thinking about it and does not appear to be useful for your case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592762/difference-between-const-const-volatile for more information

The appropiate keyword would be `const`, which tells the compiler this var mustn't be changed.

But I suspect there is another problem with your code, which will make the compiler throw an error as soon as you use `const` in the declaration.
I assume you are not using the variable correctly. You are meant to use a bitwise OR `|` in order to set the required bit **along** your actual data.

So do it like this:

```
data_byte |= bitmasking;
write8(data_byte);
```

Comment: Well, after thinking about it, I don't know, I don't think it's what I want because it may change anytime.

Comment: wtf? what may change at any time?

Comment: Sorry that method works fine. I figured out another method which is to initialize the variable in the global region with that bit set. Regards,